# Which package/program provides the Ctrl+Shift+U Unicode input utility?

Tags: unicode-entry

The title pretty much sums it up: where is this nifty functionality baked in, so I can report any bug I may encounter in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is baked in the GTK+3 code.
More specifically from the [GtkIMContext](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkIMContext.html)